# Does GPT 4 Turbo perform worse than GPT 4?

Tags: llm, gpt

GPT 4 Turbo is cheaper and accepts a longer context than GPT 4 (128k vs. 8k or 32k). Does it mean GPT 4 Turbo perform worse than GPT 4?

---

Prices from https://openai.com/pricing:

[image]

[image]